# Structuring an API response

Tags: json, api

I'm not sure on the best way to structure the response from our API.

Should every response have a 'result' or 'success' node?

I'm thinking of the following template:

```
   -result (true/false)
   -data (only if result is true)
   -errors (only if result is false)
```

Is this accepted practice, or is there a more standard way of doing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at RESTful APIs implimentations.
For errors you can use HTTP status. 
If status is 200 than everything is ok.
You can read about it here http://www.infoq.com/articles/designing-restful-http-apps-roth

Comment: OK, so the success/failure is returned via the http status code, and then just return either data or errors?

Comment: yes client usually check status code if it's ok(200), than response contains data, else it contains errors